# Hidden redirect domain name to a subfolder of an other DN using .htaccess or anything else

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, multisite

I want to redirect my domain name example.com to this domaine name  : example2.com/new/mywebsite  without changing the url(a hidden redirection)
I tried several codes in stackoverflow but it didnt work for me..

Ps : example2.com is a different website, actualy i did 2 websites with the same dashbord in wordpress the same hosting but with a different domains name.

Example 1 that doesnt work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ https://example2.com/new/website-a/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Example 2 that dosnt work too :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website-a\.example1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com/new/website-a/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on specifically what you're asking for in your first paragraph, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com/new/mywebsite [R=301,L]
```

But your examples are using different paths etc so make sure you update as needed.

Your Apache configuration files also need to be updated to ensure that `AllowOverride All` is set rather than `AllowOverride None`

This file needs to be put in the root folder of your example1 (old) domain. This is because the redirect is started when you visit the example1 site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should i put it in the htaccess where is the content of my wbesite ? here ? https://example2.com/new/website-a/ because ive just tried but nothing happening when i go to example1.com

Comment: Your htaccess file should be here in the main folder of your old website (example1.com/) because that is where the redirect in started.

Comment: I put it in example1.com/ but still doesnt work, is this redirection is visible in the url bar ?

Comment: In your Apache conf file, or your virtual host file. Make sure `AllowOverride` is set to `All` rather than `None`

Comment: Im using OVH hosting, i dont have access to the server conf :/

Comment: You may be able to edit the specific site's config file rather than the whole servers. Maybe best talk to your hosting provider for the specifics